# Is there any way to execute data provider fuction after setupBeforeClass?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a unit test class in which I want to instantiate a object from another class  in order to that I used setUpBeforeClass() fixtures of phpunit. So if I will use that recently instantiated object directly in test function then its working fine.

If i'll use this object into another function which had been created for data providers. So that object sets to null cause providers always execute first.

Is there a way to call dataProviders just before the test runs, instead?

```
require_once('Dashboard.php');
Class Someclass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected static $_dashboard;
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$_dashboard = new Dashboard();
        self::$_dashboard->set_class_type('Member');
    }
    /**
     * Test Org Thumb Image Existense
     * param org profile image : array
     * @dataProvider getOrgProfileImages
     */
    public function testFieldValidation($a,$b){
        //If I call that object function here it will give the result.
        //$members = self::$_dashboard->get_members();
       //var_dump($members); Printing result as expected
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function getOrgProfileImages() : array {
        //var_dump(self::$_dashboard);
        $members = self::$_dashboard->get_members();
        $tmp_array = ['2','2'];
        return $tmp_array;

    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {

        self::$_dashboard = null;
    }
}
```

**Error:** 
The data provider specified for Someclass::testFieldValidation is invalid.
Call to a member function get_members() on null

Please help to mitigate this issue.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but it might sound like you want to use `setUp` instead of `setUpBeforeClass`. `setUp` runs before every test instead of just once for all the tests in your file. This prevents your first test from altering the state of the object so it doesn't interfere with your other tests. Have a look at https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/fixtures.html (example 4.2)

Comment: thanks for your comment, actually I am already done with setUp fixture. Surely it will work but if there are multiple test cases then every test it will create an object of that class. I was thinking to instantiate once so that I can use it anywhere in the same class.

Comment: That "overhead" is not a problem. You actually want to have fresh instances for each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dirk-scholten is right. You SHOULD be creating a new object for each test. It's a GOOD testing practice. Frankly it looks more like you are testing the data and not testing the code, which is fine I guess, it's just not the typical use of PHPUnit. Based on the assumption that you want to make sure every user in the database has a thumbnail image (just guessing), I would go with the following:

```
<?php

class DashboardDataTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    private $dashboard;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->dashboard = new Dashboard();
    }

    /**
     * Test Org Thumb Image Existence
     * param org profile image : array
     *
     * @dataProvider getOrgProfileImages
     *
     * @param int $user_id
     */
    public function testThumbnailImageExists(int $user_id){

        $thumbnail = $this->dashboard->get_member_thumbnail($user_id);

        $this->assertNotNull($thumbnail);
    }

    public function geOrgUserIDs() : array {

        $dashboard            = new Dashboard();
        // Something that is slow
        $user_ids = $dashboard->get_all_the_member_user_ids();

        $data = [];

        foreach($user_ids as $user_id){
            $data[] = [$user_id];
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Each data provider will get called once and only once before the tests. You do not need a static data fixture on the class because phpunit handles the data fixture for you when you use data providers.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**: since I don't have the source of your `Dashboard` class, I'm using a random number in the examples below instead

Providers are invoked *before* any tests are run (and before any hooks, including `beforeClass` have a chance to run). By far the easiest way to achieve what you're after is to populate that static property on the class load:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/** @runTestsInSeparateProcesses enabled */
class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
    public static $_rand = null;

    public function provider()
    {
        $rand = self::$_rand;
        var_dump(__METHOD__, getmypid(), 'provided rand', $rand);
        return ['rand' => [$rand]];
    }

    /** @dataProvider provider */
    public function testSomething($rand)
    {
        $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
        var_dump(__METHOD__, getmypid(), 'tested with', $rand);
    }

    /** @dataProvider provider */
    public function testSomethingElse($rand)
    {
        $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
        var_dump(__METHOD__, getmypid(), 'tested with', $rand);
    }
}

// this runs before anything happens to the test case class
// even before providers are invoked

SomeTest::$_rand = rand();
```

Or you could instantiate you dashboard in the provider itself, on the first call:

```
public function provider()
{
    // Instantiate once
    if (null === self::$_rand) {
        self::$_rand = rand();
    }
    $rand = self::$_rand;
    var_dump(__METHOD__, getmypid(), 'provided rand', $rand);
    return ['rand' => [$rand]];
}
```